# Destroy only particular session with session_destroy method?

Tags: php, mysql

Actually , i have two tables in mysql database 1)admin 2)jusers. what i want is when admin logins with his email and password he redirected to super_admin page  similarly user login with email and password, he redirects to admin_user page. everything works fine, and i used two sessions for two login, And the problem is when i logout as user it will also destroys the admin session..

```
     <?php

session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect('admin_user.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);


      $stmt = $user_login->runQuery("SELECT * FROM jusers WHERE jemail=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {       

                    if($userRow['jpass']==md5($upass))
                    {    

                           $_SESSION['user']['login'] = $userRow['juid'];
                            header("Location: admin_user.php");

                    }
```

code for admin_login

```
  <?php

session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$admin_login = new USER();

if($admin_login->logged_in()!="")
{
    $admin_login->redirect('super_admin.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-adlogin']))
{
    $email = trim($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);


            $stmt = $admin_login->runQuery("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email=:email_id");
            $stmt->execute(array(":email_id"=>$email));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {       

                    if($userRow['pass']==md5($upass))
                    {    

                            $_SESSION['admin']['login'] = $userRow['auid'];
                            header("Location: super_admin.php");

                    }
```

logged methods

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']['login']))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
public function logged_in()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin']['login']))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

destroy methods

```
public function logout()
{
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['user']['login'] = false;
}

public function admin_logout()
{
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['admin']['login'] = false;
}
```

logout for user

```
 <?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$user = new USER();

if(!$user->is_logged_in())
{
    $user->redirect('login.php');
}

if($user->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user->logout();    
    $user->redirect('login.php');
}

?>
```

logout for admin

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';

$admin_user = new USER();

if(!$admin_user->logged_in())
{
    $admin_user->redirect('admin_login.php');
}

if($admin_user->logged_in()!="")
{
    $admin_user->admin_logout();    
    $admin_user->redirect('admin_login.php');
}

?>
```

what is mistake in it?

help me..

Comment: You can use unset instead of session_destroy to just unset 1 session variable when logging out.

Comment: where i can use that method?

Comment: Instead of session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['user']['login'] = false; you can say unset($_SESSION['user']['login']);

Comment: when i use unset method, it just clears the session variable data...but the session remains same...what to do

Comment: when user types admin_page URL in the browser it will display wrongs outputs

Comment: *"i used two sessions for two login"* ... actually you didn't; calling `session_start()` twice won't create 2 sessions.

Answer (score 1):

`session_destroy` removes basically all from $_SESSION , might be easier to just `unset($_SESSION['admin'])` or `unset($_SESSION['user'])` as needed.

Comment: where i can use that method?

Comment: when i use unset method, it just clears the session variable data...but the session remains same...what to doo

Answer (score -1):

just removing my answer just because there is no need. because its already answered.